# Need assistance in fetching and presenting data with PDT

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I have successfully setup Sandbo with PayPal and my own paying buttons. Now on my thankyoupage where users are redirected after a purhase I want to print the details to the user. With PDT I get the data sent, its just how I access it to present it well.

I have the data in $keyarray and this is some of the PHP code in my pdt:
Screenshot: http://snag.gy/PdsQH.jpg

```
$firstname = $keyarray['first_name'];
$lastname = $keyarray['last_name'];
$itemname = $keyarray['item_name'];
$amount = $keyarray['payment_gross'];
$id = $keyarray['item_number'];

echo ("<div id='welcomeText'>Thank you for your purchase!</div>");
echo ("<p><div id='bold'>Payment Details</div></p><br>\n");
echo ("<div class='abouttext'>Name: $firstname $lastname</div>\n");

$string1 = 'item_number';
$string2 = 'item_name';
$string3 = 'quantity';
$count = count($keyarray);
for($idx = 1; $idx < $count; $idx ++) {
if (isset($string2) && 'item_name' != null)
echo ("<div class='abouttext'>Item name: ".$keyarray[$string2.$idx]."</div>\n");
echo ("<div class='abouttext'>Item ID: ".$keyarray[$string1.$idx]."</div>\n");
echo ("<div class='abouttext'>Qty: ".$keyarray[$string3.$idx]."</div>\n");

}
```

The problem is that it loops 65 times since it is that long. I would like to change $count = count($keyarray); to instead count the times item_number is in $keyarray, something like 
$count = count($keyarray['item_number'); - is that possible? I could also hardcode in 10 instead of $count and make it loop 10 times, and the result wouldnt be THAT bad.

Comment: where are `item_number4` & `item_number5` ?

Comment: They arent used yet but will make no difference. I need to know how to loop through the sent transationID ($keyarray) and for every occurence of $id / item_number i echo the details of that product.

Comment: Now the $id in foreach ($keyarray as $id) is just the value of every entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: better if you can alter the contents of `$keyarray` at source.

You can create names in a loop:

e.g.

```
$string = 'item_name';

$arr_val = array(
        'item_name1' => 'Kot1',
        'item_name2' => 'Kot2',
        'item_name3' => 'Kot3',
        'item_name4' => 'Kot4',
        'item_name5' => 'Kot5'
        );


for($idx =1; $idx < 6; $idx ++) {
    var_dump($arr_val[$string.$idx]);
}
```

this will output:

> string 'Kot1' (length=4)
>
> string 'Kot2' (length=4)
>
> string 'Kot3' (length=4)
>
> string 'Kot4' (length=4)
>
> string 'Kot5' (length=4)

EDIT: Use below code to find actual Item-Numbers in `$keyarray`.

```
$array_keys = array_keys($keyarray);
$count =0;
foreach($array_keys as $element) {
    if (!strncmp('item_number', $element, strlen('item_number')))
        $count++;
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you! With this code:  
`$string1 = 'item_number';
 $string2 = 'item_name';
 for($idx = 1; $idx < 6; $idx ++) {
 echo ($keyarray[$string2.$idx]);
 echo ($keyarray[$string1.$idx]);
}` I get both Name and Id printed successfully. But now the next question is how can I manipulate the looks of it? I tried with:
`echo ("<div class='abouttext'>Item ID: ($keyarray[$string1.$idx])</div>\n"); ` But it isnt valid code

Comment: just split the string : `echo ("<div class='abouttext'>Item ID: (".$keyarray[$string1.$idx].")</div>\n");`

Comment: Thx, I solved it by having several lines and echos, but your solution looks a lot nicer...
Now this outputs: http://snag.gy/PdsQH.jpg
The problem I now have is that it prints the whole array-length everytime. Is there a way to edit this: `$count = count($keyarray);` to for example `$count = count($keyarray[item_number]);` so I get equal to the different item_number ie different products in their basket insetad of 65 which are all entries that is beeing sent.

Comment: I'm not really getting what you're saying, hence I asked in the beginning `where are the missing item numbers`.

Comment: I should update the first post. I dont need anything else than $itemname = $keyarray['item_name']; and $id = $keyarray['item_number']; since the loop. I get all data correct, only it prints / loops 65 times because of this:
 $count = count($keyarray);
 for($idx = 1; $idx < $count; $idx ++) and I need the $count to just count the times item_name that is being sent to set the loop to loop that many times. I could hard-code in 3 and I would get good result now, but not when there are more products. Hard to explain!

Comment: added another piece of code for finding actual `item_number` count.